# Using a Sequence on Create or Update in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have created a sequence in a migration that I want to be used in both creates and updates. I'm thinking that I can create a before save filter that will setup the sequence, but I'm not sure how to 'inject' the SQL required (in this case `nextval('sequence')`). My query will need to look something like this:

```
UPDATE users
SET 
sequence=nextval('users_sequence'),
name='Kevin',
...
WHERE id=...
```

Note that I unfortunately cannot create a trigger to do this as I am deploying on Heroku's shared database and don't have access to PLPGSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `before_filter` write something like:

```
User.connection.select_value("SELECT nextval('users_sequence')")
```

Hope this helps.